# Attachments not coming to library from sharepoint 2010 Incoming Email

Tags: sharepoint-server, incoming-email

I have enabled incoming email in SharePoint 2010 server.

I have setup SMTP with **< local domain >.local** as default and **< Alias Domain 2 >.com** as alias

Here i am sending mails to **< Alias Domain 2 >.com**. from an external laptop which is not connected to this. I am able to receive those mail in server inside Drop folder.

I tested by configuring both **< local domain >.local** and **< Alias Domain 2 >.com** in central admin.

Timer jobs is running and after email Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail is run, email Disappearing from Drop folder, Time job status is success.

But the email or attachment in email is not coming to library. How to check where it is going. Please help.

Update :-
In Event Viewer throwing warning as

```
An error occurred while processing the incoming e-mail file C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\a546e84f01d2560e00000002.eml.
The error was: Access denied.
You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

But the user running this job is having full access on this folder security.

Comment: Are there 2 or more AD accounts that have the same email address?

Comment: @VirajGorajia Actualy i am sending email from some other provider, It isn't same provider, and i have set settings to accept email from all users

Comment: Yes i understand, but have you added same email address to more than 1 AD user?

Comment: @VirajGorajia sorry i am not getting your point, i am sending email from external provider. not from internal ad user.

Comment: Error is coming in Incoming email. So your To email is defined to any SharePoint user. Have you added To email to multiple SharePoint users?

Comment: no its unique now its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialy i have not set property to accept email from all users so it was not working. After setting also was same, don't know why, but after running

```
$site.RefreshEmailEnabledObjects()
```

It satarted working.